# Bash - remove all starting with, but not ending with

Tags: bash, glob

Im trying to write a command that deletes all files/folders starting with "test", expcet zip files that also start with test.

So far i have:

```
 rm -rf test*[!zip]
```

This almost works, but not quite.

If i have following files:

```
test
test1
test.zip
```

Then after the command remaining are:

```
test
test.zip
```

So the problem is that test should also be deleted. I understand that my command only matches things that have at least one extra character besides "test", but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Note that in your case `[!zip]` is not a fixed pattern saying exclude `zip`, it is saying exclude `z`, `i` or `p`. For pattern excludes, use the `extglob` approach as indicated in anubhava's answer

Answer (score 1):

Your glob pattern `test*[!zip]` will require at least one character after `test` due to presence of `[!zip]` part.

You may use this extended glob pattern in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
printf '%s\n' test!(*zip)
```

Or else, you may use this `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name 'test*' -not -name 'test*zip'
```